# Space leak only in certain cases in GHC interpreter when doing: concat <some list> !! n

Tags: haskell, ghc

I define my own version of `concat`, `myConcat`:

```
module Eh where

myConcat []          = []
myConcat ([]:os)     = myConcat os
myConcat ((x:xs):os) = x : myConcat (xs:os)

(!!!)  :: [a] -> Int -> a
xs     !!! n | n < 0 = error "negative index"
[]     !!! _         = error "index too large"
(x:_)  !!! 0         = x
(_:xs) !!! n         = xs !!! (n-1)
```

If I do `myConcat <some huge list> !! n` in the GHC interpreter, it steals my memory at 300MB/s, and I have to kill it before it can summon the OOM killer. Note here that I load `Eh` as "interpreted", I don't compile it before loading it.

```
code run in the GHC interpreter        space leak?
myConcat (repeat [1,2,3,4]) !! (10^8)  Yes
concat (repeat [1,2,3,4]) !! (10^8)    No
myConcat (repeat [1,2,3,4]) !!! (10^8) No
concat (repeat [1,2,3,4]) !!! (10^8)   No
```

Now if I compile `Eh` (`ghc --make -O2  Eh.hs`), and then load it in the interpreter and re-run these tests, none of them space leak. Same if I compile each test case instead of running them in the interpreter.

What's going on?

---

I'm running GHC 6.12.3.

Comment: What version of ghci are you using? I have constant memory in all four cases on my machine. I have ghc `7.0.3` or something like that.

Comment: I'm running 6.12.3. Thanks for testing! Is 6.12.3 outdated?

Comment: "What's going on?" - well, optimization (`-O2`), for one thing. :)

Comment: why is there even a space leak in the first place?

Comment: I could reproduce it, and it is not only optimization – if I compile the file with ```-O0```, it does not leak, while running ghci with ```-O2``` does not help. My guess would be that the garbage collector does not run correctly for some reason that is not clear to me. But luckily the bug is fixed in later versions :-)

Comment: @muratgu: I reverted your edit because this is about a space leak (allocating too much), not a memory leak (losing reference to allocated memory).

Comment: I don't know either what causes the leak, but it seems to be a bug present only in 6.12. I tested with 6.10.4, 6.12.3, 7.0.2, 7.0.4 and 7.2.1, the only version exhibiting the leak was 6.12.3. Trying to diagnose it by running ghci with +RTS -hT made it run in constant memory (but much higher than the other versions, ~120MB).

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is strictness. Evaluation in Haskell is non-strict, so computations are usually performed only if their results are really needed. Instead, a so-called thunk is created that represents the not-yet-performed computation.

In certain cases the compiler can however detect that the result of the computation will be needed anyway and therefore replaces the creation of thunks by the actual computation.

The [Haskell Wiki](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Performance/Strictness) probably explains this better.

To fix your `myConcat` function you have to make sure it doesn't create millions of thunks by manually forcing strict evaluation. One (not very pretty looking) way of doing this could be:

```
myConcat []          = []
myConcat ([]:os)     = myConcat os
myConcat ((x:xs):os) = ((:) $! x) myConcat (xs:os)
```

Comment: I don't think that's the issue here. The leak occurs only with ghc-6.12 and only with interpreted code. If it were just strictness, the leak should also occur with other versions, and also in (unoptimised) compiled code. Looks more like a corner-case bug in 6.12's byte-code generator to me.

Comment: Maybe, but why does my version of `myConcat` work then? The only change is the strict apply.

Comment: Yes, of course laziness has a part in it, and by introducing the right strictness annotations, the leak can be avoided. What I meant is that normally, the byte-code generated by ghci treats the original definition well, so the manifestation of the leak points rather to a problem in 6.12's byte-code generator than to a problem with the non-strictness of the definition per se.